# RestTemplate exchange change convert behaviour for specific returned value from rest api

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate to retrieve Employee object via rest api:

```
 ResponseEntity<Employee> e2=rt.exchange("http://localhost:8080/empl", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Employee.class, new ArrayList());
        Employee emp2 = e2.getBody();
```

Normally http://localhost:8080/empl return json that could be converted into Employee class object, however, when employee is not found, the api returns String "Not found" instead of json that could be converted into empty object Employee and exchange crashes during conversion.

My question is: Is it possible to force exchange to convert String "Not found" to empty Employee object, or empty array of Employee objects ?

Best Regards,
Piotr

Comment: why cant you check for the http status and decide accordingly ? `e2.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful() ? e2.getBody() : new Employee()` .

Comment: 1. HttpMessageNotReadableException will be thrown while exchange, You don't have chance to check status. 2. I would like to return this empty Employee only if api return String "Not found"

Comment: Read it as string and use Jackson for conversion post Status check? ResponseEntity<String>